# Joining WordLists in python

Tags: python, textblob

I need to extract `ngrams` from `text`. I'm using:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
text = TextBlob('me king of python')
print(text.ngrams(n=3)
```

to split the text (me king of python) in trigrams, and it gives:

```
[WordList(['me', 'king', 'of']), WordList(['king', 'of', 'python'])]
```

now i need to join the items of each WordList with:

```
x = {word for word in ' '.join(text.ngrams(n=3)) }
print x
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string or Unicode, WordList found
```

I know the solution is silly but i'm not good in python and I don't understand `wordlists`.

Comment: ngrams? WordLists? Is this an `nltk` question? Please tag as such, because these aren't going to be familiar to a general Python audience.

Comment: What the freak is `WordList`? `ngrams`?

Comment: `{word for word in ' '.join(text.ngrams(n=3)) }` doesn't make sense - that's just `set(''.join(...))`. Also you're not *"[joining] the items of each WordList"*, you're trying to join all of the word lists together. Did you want something like `map(''.join, text.ngrams(n=3))` (i.e. join up the words *within* each `WordList`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Third [interrobang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang) this morning. Is your blood pressure OK? :)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fortunately, it's almost home time here...

Comment: @user2598997 specify the name of python package/library , you use for  extracting n-grams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> blob = TextBlob('me king of python')
>>> trigram = blob.ngrams(n=3)
>>> for wlist in trigram:
...     print ' '.join(wlist)
me king of
king of python
```

Even better, use a for loop since the text could have multiple `WordLists`.

#### Update

It's also possible to achieve the same thing using pure Python. Here is an example:

```
>>> def ngrams(s, n=2, i=0):
...     while len(s[i:i+n]) == n:
...             yield s[i:i+n]
...             i += 1
...
>>> grams = ngrams('me king of Python'.split())
>>> list(grams)
[['me', 'king'], ['king', 'of'], ['of', 'Python']]
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you